# Controller 'ngMessages', required by directive 'ngMessage', can't be found

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Hi I developing an app using angularjs (1.5.0) following jonhpapa rules.
Also I use angular material 1.0.6.

I have a problem when I add the module 'ngMessages'.

I installed the lib angular-messages 1.5.1.

When I add the module to use I have the following error on console.

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngMessages', required by directive 'ngMessage', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngMessages&p1=ngMessage
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at getControllers (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8817:19)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8982:33)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8226:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8973:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8226:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8229:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8229:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8229:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8229:13) <div data-ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

This view at this moment doesn't have controller. The view contains:

```
         <md-input-container>
            <label>First name</label>
            <input name="firstName" 
              ng-model="vm.user.firstName"
              md-maxlength="30" 
              required>
              <div ng-messages="vm.user.firstName.$error">
                <div ng-message="md-maxlength">Field has to be less than 30 characters long.</div>
                <div ng-message="required">Field required</div>
              </div>
          </md-input-container>
```

Thanks in advance, regards.

Comment: make sure the angular-messages js file is included in your html.

Comment: @lansen Its generated by gulp, and I see icluded in the HTML.

Comment: you can't use directive if you don't have a controller. Message is very clear: `Controller 'ngMessages', required by directive 'ngMessage'`. Add to body tag: `ng-controller="ngMessages"`

Comment: @dpaul1994 I tryed to put a controller, and doesnt work.

Comment: Edit your question and add the exactly controller and directive + html for that

Comment: @dpaul1994 This isn't the issue. You don't need to add your own `ngMessage` controller. The documentation doesn't mention this.

Comment: same problem here, in a md-dialog... Any solution?

Answer (score 7):

To fix the problem replace the following:

ng-message by ng-messages

It is a typing error.

Answer (score 5):

Your `ng-messages` needs to contain the form's name and then the input field's name.

So: `formName.fieldName.$error`

Then the `ng-message` needs to contain the validation rule (like you have).

If you don't have a form surrounding your `md-input-container` you need to add one.

The form name can be whatever you want.

Something similar to this:

```
<form name="vm.details">

    <md-input-container>
        <label>First name</label>
        <input name="firstName" 
          ng-model="vm.user.firstName"
          md-maxlength="30" 
          required>
          <div ng-messages="vm.details.firstName.$error">
            <div ng-message="md-maxlength">Field has to be less than 30 characters long.</div>
            <div ng-message="required">Field required</div>
          </div>
      </md-input-container>

</form>
```